# Bind rows NSRuleEditor with array

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray

In developer documentation i found this:

> `NSRuleEditor` exposes one binding, `rows`. You can bind `rows` to an
>   ordered collection (such as an instance of `NSMutableArray`). Each
>   object in the collection should have the following properties:
>
> - @"rowType" An integer representing the type of the row(NSRuleEditorRowType).
> - @"subrows" An ordered to-many relation (such as an instance of    NSMutableArray) containing the directly nested subrows for the given
>     row.
> - @"displayValues" An ordered to-many relation containing the display    values for the row.
> - @"criteria" An ordered to-many relation containing the criteria for    the row.

Anybody may give an example how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

=========== EDIT =============

As I researched, the `NSRuleEditor` class header contains the next documentation about binding:

```
* -- Bindings support -- */

/* Sets the class used when creating a new row in the "rows" binding; this class should be KVC and KVO compliant for the key paths listed below.  By default this is NSMutableDictionary */
- (void)setRowClass:(Class)rowClass;
- (Class)rowClass;

/* Set and get the key path for the row type, which is used to get the row type in the "rows" binding.  The row type is a value property of type NSRuleEditorRowType.  The default is @"rowType". */
- (void)setRowTypeKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath;
- (NSString *)rowTypeKeyPath;

/* Set and get the key path for the subrows, which is used to determined nested rows in the "rows" binding.  The subrows property is an ordered to-many relationship containing additional bound row objects. The default is @"subrows". */
- (void)setSubrowsKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath;
- (NSString *)subrowsKeyPath;

/* Set and get the criteria key path, which determines the criteria for a row in the "rows" binding.  (The criteria objects are what the delegate returns from - ruleEditor: child: forCriterion: withRowType:).  The criteria property is an ordered to-many relationship. The default is @"criteria". */
- (void)setCriteriaKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath;
- (NSString *)criteriaKeyPath;

/* Set and get the display values key path, which determines the display values for a row (the display values are what the delegate returns from - ruleEditor: displayValueForCriterion: inRow:).  The criteria property is an ordered to-many relationship. The default is @"displayValues". */
- (void)setDisplayValuesKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath;
- (NSString *)displayValuesKeyPath;
```

And to expand the answer, I am giving the next example so you'll understand how to bind your own class as rows:

```
@interface BindObject : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger rowType;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *subrows;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *displayValues;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *criteria;

@end

// binding custom class as row class
[self.ruleEditor setRowClass:[BindObject class]];
```

Now as you add new rows to `NSRuleEditor` your class will be used. You also can change KeyPath so fields (ivars/properties) in your custom row class may be called differently than it's speicifed in documentation.

Hope this will help you to understand how NSRuleEditor works.

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

I've found [this article](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=948727), it should help you understand how NSRuleEditor works.

Comment: Regrettably the article and example code do not cover how to bind "rows" with an NSRuleEditor.